# Adding a class to a button in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to add a css class to my button after some ajax:

```
$('a.vote-up-0').click(function() {

    var id = $(this).siblings('.reply-id').val();
    var ajax_auth_token = $('#auth_token').val();


    $.post('user/?action=ajax', {
        vote_type: 'up',
        reply_id: id,
        auth_token: ajax_auth_token
    }, function(data, return_status) {   

        var json_data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

        switch(json_data.r_message)
        {
           case "success": 
              output = "Yay it works!"; // change 
               alert(output);
               $(this).addClass('vote-up-1'); // ** the culprit **
           break;
```

The alert works, however it does not add the class vote-up-1 to it. There are several instances of the same class (i.e. vote-up-0) on the page, so If I change (this) to 'vote-up-0', it changes all of them. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: put alert after the culprit line and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brother: `$(this).addClass('vote-up-1'); // ** the culprit **` is truly the culprit. `$(this)` is not available in this scope so it's better that you get the handle of the button before doing any ajax. such as:

`var btnHnd = $(this);` Now you can do the post stuff: `$.post('user/?action=ajax', { ...`

Answer (score 2):

Up at the top of your "click" handler, stash the `this` value:

```
var theButton = this;
```

Then, in your ".post()" handler:

```
$(theButton).addClass('vote-up-1');
```

The problem is that `this` will not refer to the button when jQuery calls your ".post()" handler.  Thus, you save a copy into a local variable, and it'll be there waiting for the handler when the time comes.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
 $(putyourbuttonidhere).addClass('vote-up-1');
```